# Amazon S3 Different Download Speeds for File Sizes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm wanting to know if my theory is true, I have the following files hosted on S3:-

- Single 83.9 MB ZIP File
- The Single ZIP File separated into 12 files
- The Single ZIP File separated into 24 files

I was assuming the single ZIP file would have the best results but this doesn't appear to be the case.

Latest Result

- Single: 31 minutes
- 12 Files: 2.8 minutes
- 24 Files: 6 minutes

The single file download in particular varies in speeds, I've had results ranging from 15 minutes to 35 minutes for this file.

Question: Does Amazon S3 have different download methods/speeds for different file sizes?

Comment: An order of magnitude difference seems like an awful lot. Are you sure there isn't some other effect causing this?

Comment: 2nd Test - Single: 16.5 minutes - 12 Files: 2.5 minutes - 24 Files: 4.25 minutes

Comment: Nothing should be affecting the results, it's the same bit of code testing each download speed and I don't have anything running on my Mac to interfere.

Answer (score 1):

No amazon s3 does not have different method of different count of download. It will be better if you let us know which tool you are using for downloading your data. because if your tool is allowing your to download your data in parallel thread (process) then your part operation will take less time than single file processing time.

Second the download time may vary because of internet speed too.

Comment: I created the script in a separate Xcode mobile project to simply test download speeds. Performing a simple HTTP request, one request at a time.

Comment: Then it is possibility that whatever tool you are using, while downloading the file (size in MB's), in between the download process "connection timeout" such error occurring and restart the download process again. so big file taking time to finish the process.

Comment: I haven't set the script to restart the download if it fails, so if a timeout did occur, it would simply stop.